# In mysql integer 8.5 storing as 8.0

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to insert integer 1.5 with PHP in mysql db but numbers inserting as 1.0, 2.0 how to insert as I need correctly (1.5)?

```
$number = 1.5;
```

number mysql data type: `number numeric(3,2);`

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE scores SET number = ? WHERE id = 1');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $number);
```

UPDATED:
Problem was `$stmt->bind_param('i', $number);` it was updating mysql record as integer (i) (1). Correct use `$stmt->bind_param('d', $number);` Before updating entry decelerating in $stmt it as (d) double (1.5).

Comment: What is your `number` field `Datatype` in your  `scores` table?

Comment: Please use `number` datatype `FLOAT` and  Length `15,2`. i hope solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

First 1 and 2 are **integers 1.5 is float or double** value which means that your value type in this field must match this type. Try to change its type.

Second I think that ID in table if it is a **primary key cannot be then autoincremented if type is double/float** so you need to be sure that every record in database table is correct.

I want you also to ask why you want push an float/double to ID its not a good choice of choosing name for number in table. Better way is to have unique identifier name ID is not one of the best because it determines something primary in **mysql**.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `number` datatype `FLOAT` and Length `15,2`. i hope solve you problem.